# Exclude custom taxonomy using Query Post

Tags: wordpress

I have made a custom taxonomy called `portfolio-categories` and made a category that I want to exclude from my post query. I have added it to the post query, but those posts are still displaying.

Here is the code I have used:

```
query_posts( array(
    'post_type'=> 'portfolio',
    'orderby'=>'menu_order',
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-categories',
        'terms' => 7,
        'field' => 'id',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
    )
) );
```

Can anyone spot the issue here? From the documentation this looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `new WP_query()`

```
$args=array('post_type'   => 'portfolio',
            'taxonomy'    => 'product-category',
            'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
            'order'       => 'ASC',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'cat'         => 7
  );
$query = new WP_query($args);
while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

     ......

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$args=array(
           'post_type' => 'portfolio',
           'taxonomy'=>'product-category',
           'orderby'=>'menu_order',
           'order'=>'ASC',
           'term' => 'usluge-proizvodi',
           'post__not_in' => array(330,341),
           'post_status' => 'publish',
           'posts_per_page' => 8
      );
```